# I want to list the users who have reacted to Discord. for Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to list the users who have reacted to Discord.

```
let MyChannel = client.channels.get('573534660852711426');
    MyChannel.fetchMessage('656352072806957066').then(themessage => {
    for (const reaction of themessage.reactions){
        for (let user of reaction.users){
            console.log(user);
        }
        console.log(reaction);
    }
});
```

This is my code, but it doesn't work. Can you help me.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does it give you an error, an incorrect answer or does nothing happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Reaction.fetchUsers`. Try something like that:

```js
let MyChannel = client.channels.get('573534660852711426');
    MyChannel.fetchMessage('656352072806957066').then(async themessage => {
    for (const reaction of themessage.reactions){
        for (let user of await reaction.fetchUsers(){
            console.log(user);
        }
        console.log(reaction);
    }
});
```

I edited `reaction.users` with `await reaction.fetchUsers()` and I added `async` because `await` must be used in an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

The error I get when I run the code is as follows.

````
    at F:\js\index.js:41:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:23364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:23364) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```

38 let MyChannel = bot.channels.get('648985076817985556');
39      MyChannel.fetchMessage('650431271436156969').then(async themessage => {
40          for (const reaction of themessage.reactions){
41              for (let user of await reaction.fetchUsers()){
42                  console.log(user);
43              }
44              console.log(reaction);
45          }
46      });
````